# valgrind realloc error: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c, reference, stack, valgrind, realloc

```
==17209== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==17209==    at 0x402E7C5: __GI___rawmemchr (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==17209==    by 0x40CE921: _IO_str_init_static_internal (strops.c:45)
==17209==    by 0x40B0B76: __isoc99_vsscanf (isoc99_vsscanf.c:42)
==17209==    by 0x8048647: main (lala.c:23)
==17209==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==17209==    at 0x8048659: gatherInfoSalt (lala.c:28)
==17209==
```

.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>


struct sysinfo_s {
    char *salt_id;
};


void gatherInfoSalt(char ** );

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sysinfo_s si;

    si.salt_id = malloc(1);
    *si.salt_id = 0;

    gatherInfoSalt(&si.salt_id);

    free(si.salt_id);
}

void gatherInfoSalt(char ** salt_id) {
    FILE * fp;
    char buf[256];
    int r;


    if (!(fp = fopen("/etc/salt/minion.d/id.conf","r"))) {
            perror("fopen");
        return;
    }

    r=fread(buf,1,255,fp);

    //adding *buf=0 here removes the error (but removes functionality)

    if (r) {
        *salt_id=realloc(*salt_id,r-2);
        **salt_id=0;
        sscanf(buf,"id:%s",*salt_id);
        //sscanf(buf,"id:%s",buf1);
    }

    printf("saltid: %s\n",*salt_id);

    fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: What is the value of `r`? Are you sure that it is initialized?

Comment: yes. There is an r=fread(); if(r) { **salt_id=realloc()...}. I just found out that just commenting out sscanf removes the error for some reason.

Comment: And the content of `buf` comes from... ? *Post a MCVE please*. And for heaven sake, *check your IO call results*.

Comment: I updated the code with the previous part. The code works fine.

Comment: @WhozCraig Adding a *buf=0 after the fread removes the valgrind error, but destroys functionality

Comment: @WhozCraig Added MCVE

Comment: Why are you subtracting 2 from `r` when you call `realloc`?

Comment: no need really, but because it won't include id:.

Comment: I found it, it needs a buf[r]=0 after fread..

Comment: You shouldn't subtract anything. `r` will be `1`, so if you subtract anything you won't allocate any space.

Comment: @Barmar fread returns number of (1-byte) items read.

Comment: Oops, I was confused, I was thinking it was `read()`, and saw `1` as the buffer size.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using `fgets()` instead of `fread`, so you read a whole line and it automatically terminates it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
r=fread(buf,1,255,fp);
sscanf(buf,"id:%s",....
```

should be:

```
  r=fread(buf,1,255,fp);
  buf[r]=0;
  sscanf(buf,"id:%s",....
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the buf when it is declared or memset it to 0 before fread.

Comment: yes, memset works too, I prefer to set just 1 byte though. Thanks.